# Autenticar usuário e senha de uma outra página

Tags: javascript, css, html5

Preciso criar um formulário e enviar método "POST" os dados para autenticar em outro site. Gostaria de saber como é feito, até mesmo pq quando apertar o botão "Logar" tem que acessar normalmente como se tivesse entrando pelo próprio site.

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode informar a pagina de login do outro site no formulário.

```
<form method="POST" action="https://seusite.com/site02login.php">
 <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
 <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
 <button type="submit">Acessar Conta</button>
<form>
```

Dai o https://seusite.com/site02login.php vai receber o POST!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso usando fetch do próprio javascript ou optar por lib como axios.
não é muito difícil;

Esse é o HTML

```
<form method="POST">
   <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" />
   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" />
   <button type="submit">Acessar Conta</button>
<form>
```

JavaScript

```
const button = document.querySelector('button[type="submit"]');
const handleLogin = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    const email = document.getElementById('email'),
          password = document.getElementById('password');
    fetch('http://myapi.com/api/v1/login', { email, password })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
button.addEventListener('click', handleLogin);
```